# How to simplify D[(1/2).m.(X[t]^2), {X[t]}]

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like to simplify the following expression:

```
D[(1/2).m.(X[t]^2), {X[t]}]// Rationalize // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm
```

This should evaluates to:

```
m.X(t)
```

However in mathematica it evaluates to:

```
(1/2).m.(2 X(t))
```

I've tried Chop, Rationalize, Simplify, FullSimplify.

This is a dressed down example, my equations are more complex and become very unreadable because of this..

Comment: What do you mean by `(1/2).m...`? Is `(1/2) `a matrix, or it is simply one half?

Comment: (1/2) simply means a half and m and X[t] are variables, not vectors or matrices.

Comment: Do you mean to try `D[(1/2)*m*(X[t]^2), {X[t]}] // Rationalize // 
  FullSimplify // TraditionalForm`?, which evaluates to `m X(t)`? When you write "A.B", do you mean to multiply the matrices? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MultiplyingVectorsAndMatrices.html. Ignore me if not...

Comment: It seems that the question is the result of s simple mistake in the basic syntax. I propose to put this question on hold.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** I started from the assumption that m and X are matrices, because of the `Dot`function you used.
Then the following is valid: 
Try this:

```
expr = D[(1/2)*m.X[t]^2, X[t]]

(*  1/2 m.(2 X[t])  *)
```

then

```
 expr /. Dot[a_, Times[2, b_]] -> Times[2, Dot[a, b]]

(*   m.X[t]   *)
```

As soon as you state that they are simple variables, just replace the `Dot`(.) by the multiplication sign (*) and you get the result automatically.

Have fun!

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: +1. This might be a suitable generalization: `Dot[a_, Times[k_?NumericQ, b_]] :> Times[k, Dot[a, b]]` or even this, which seems to work with `$Assumptions` to handle symbolic scalars: `Dot[a_, Times[k_, b_]] /; Simplify[k \[Element] Complexes] :> Times[k, Dot[a, b]]`.  (Not extensively tested.)